# Parsing a String with an Exponent (Java)

Tags: java, string, parsing, int, double

I have a string similar to: `7.6E+7`.

My question is simple: How do I turn this into its corresponding number: `76000000`?

I have tried using `substring` to isolate the `E+7` part, then parse the `7` part, then move the decimal places over 7. Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long n = Double.valueOf("7.6E+7").longValue();
System.out.println(d);
// prints 76000000 to the output.
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29):

```
double val = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

where `str` is the input string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Double.parseDouble() to get it as a number.

```
String e = "7.6E+7";
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(e));
```

Giving the output 7.6E7. If you do not want the E in the output you can use

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
f.setGroupingUsed(false);
System.out.println(f.format(Double.parseDouble(e)));
```

Which will give you the output 76000000 without casting to a whole number. Eg adding 0.1 to the number will give the output 76000000.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the number can ultimately be cast into an integer without losing precision than alternatively you could do:

```
int d = (int) Double.parseDouble("7.6E+7");
System.out.println(d);
```

Which prints `76000000` to the output.